# need help to get Facebook profile picture. Also is GRAPH Api online test site down?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I followed the instructions from github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

and can get Facebook login dialog and get connected. It's for ipad application to get FB info. user name, friend list can be fetched correctly.

I tried to get the profile picture

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture" andDelegate:self];
```

and received response:There was a problem communicating with server...

but similar calls like

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/posts" andDelegate:self];

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

work just fine.

also tried the facebook graph API online test site:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

to use it, first get access token, then tried to get posts, friends, and they are fine.

but when to get picture will take forever, and never return anything.

I did log into my facebook account in a web browser and the profile picture appears just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graph API for the `user` endpoint is described here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

About the picture connection, it says:

> HTTP 302 redirect to URL of the user's profile picture (use ?type=square | small | normal | large to request a different photo).

So what you get is not the typical JSON response, but the picture itself (via the HTTP redirect). You can try that by entering the graph API call into your browser location bar. For example, to see the profile pic of Mark Zuckerberg, try:
http://graph.facebook.com/markzuckerberg/picture